# CSS Hover state not working

Tags: html, css

I have a code like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: -22px; margin-top: -22px; left: 502px; top: 379px; z-index: 380; display: block;" class="maptimize_marker_0 f st">1<span class="pinlabel">1B 100E</span></div>
```

I also have CSS for pinlabel

```
.pinlabel{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #3774d5;
height: 16px;
width: 200px;
color: white;
top: 0px;
left: 1px;
font-size: 10px !important;
border-radius: 10px;
border: white 2px solid;}

.maptimize_marker_0:hover span.pinlabel {display:block;}
```

But I cant get the Hover state work. If to Force hover state in developer tool in chrome everything works fine, but not working when mouse is over... What am I doing wrong? Also I want to put span Under the div, but the span is always on top and covers the div background picture... Please help!

Comment: Change Position: absolute to Position : relative. I guess this might be the problem.

Comment: Seems to work in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/TPfg2/

Comment: Can you please see it here, I know there is no mistake, but I cant figure out why it doesnt work http://107.170.236.227/map/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, on http://jsfiddle.net/abrunet/Bb9T3/, I copy paste your code and the `hover` is working..

Last, your span does not have a `z-index` specified. You might chose one, lower than the divs one and an other higher for the `hover` case.

You should also try to separate your style in a different sheet to keep your code clean.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Abrunet, Thank you for the answer. I tried everything, maybe you can have a look at the code. The needed line can be easily found by search for "1B 100E"

107.170.236.227/map/index2.html

Comment: The search doesn't result anything. Your question should reflect your real problem ^^ It's quite different from what you explained first, isn't it? Why are you not using the google map tools to create that text which can pop up above the marker? See the google map docs. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: It's quite different from what you explained first, isn't it? - why you think so?
Why are you not using the google map tools to create that text which can pop up above the marker? - it doesnt fit my needs The infowindow can not be styled the way I will need it to be...actually it can not be styled anyhow, google api is not a good thing to use) Search for 1B 100E without the brackets, please.

Comment: The fact you use the map kind of complicate the case... 

Have you check that tutorial? http://medelbou.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/creating-a-tooltip-for-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/

I feel like what you need stay close to the provided google features.